# ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException: Failed to marshal the Objective-C (type: Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_HeaderWrapperView)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Thanks,

Complete error:
*ObjCRuntime.RuntimeException: Failed to marshal the Objective-C object 0x7fc8fc575d30 (type: Xamarin_Forms_Platform_iOS_HeaderWrapperView). Could not find an existing managed instance for this object, nor was it possible to create a new managed instance (because the type 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.HeaderWrapperView' does not have a constructor that takes one IntPtr argument)*

I have a details page which loads data from the API asynchronously, The data retrieval can take huge time depending on the size of data. the data retrieved is loaded into a listview through binding. The listview has grouping and has a group template defined. While the data is loading in a background thread, user can do other actions- this is a per the design.

The switching between the pages is easier since the main page is a split view where left is a selectable list, and selected items detail page is on the right which is the page we just discussed.

The issue is when the user selects other item on the left while the data was loading asynchronously, the new page would now shown up and the previous page would be in the verge of destroying or becoming stale. During this event, previous page data is retrieved from the endpoint- the binding initiates on the previous page which is now not available. This is somehow causing app to crash intermittently by below errors.

Not sure why, the error stack shows the error begins from the elements created in the group header such has **Image/ActivityIndicator** ..
such as below:
*Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateParentPageAccessibilityElements () [0x0001a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:529 at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00131] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:414
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer`2[TView,TNativeView].OnElementPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00078] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\ViewRenderer.cs:158
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ActivityIndicatorRenderer.OnElementPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\Renderers\ActivityIndicatorRenderer.cs:38*

or

at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject[T] (System.IntPtr ptr) [0x000d1] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:1260
at UIKit.UIView.get_Superview () [0x0002a] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/14.0.0.0/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIView.g.cs:4848
*Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].UpdateParentPageAccessibilityElements () [0x0001a] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:529 at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1[TElement].OnElementPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00131] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\VisualElementRenderer.cs:414
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ViewRenderer`2[TView,TNativeView].OnElementPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) [0x00078] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS\ViewRenderer.cs:158
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ImageRenderer.<>n__1 (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)*

**Any thoughts on how the binding should behave when the page itself is not available? and Is this is a known issue in iOS?**

Comment: Hi, have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9711), may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I visited this page- didn't help much as I don't see the workaround for this fix other than updating to custom Nuget

Comment: Yeah, the issue seems not to be solved. I can see there is a open issue at the last of there, then we can continue to follow that up. If there are any good ideas we can know that later.